# Using binomial approximation to calculate probability

Tags: r, probability, self-study

Question is as follows:

In a shipment of $20$ engines, history shows that the probability of any one engine proving unsatisfactory is $0.1$.

a) Use the Binomial approximation to calculate the probability that at least three engines are defective?

Since the question is asking to calculate the probability that AT LEAST three engines are defective, the following code should be correct.

```
sum(pbinom(3:20,20,0.1))
```

Looking for confirmation I am on the right path.

Comment: are you asking for the exact probability that is calc. by binomial or normal approx. to binomial?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is correct. However, we are summing up $18$ terms.

We could have computed $$1-\sum_{i=0}^2P(X=i)=1-\sum_{i=0}^2 \binom{20}{i}0.1^i0.9^{20-i}$$

instead.